# Using an RPC like Protocol Buffers as a backend to Django, instead of MySQL or SQLite

Tags: django, django-admin, rpc, protocol-buffers

The clever folks behind the [app-engine-patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) project have essentially enabled all the fun stuff of Django, including the admin, but without using Django's ORM.

From their website:

> The most important change is that you have to use Google's *Model* class because the development model is too different from Django (at least with Django's current API).

This is essentially what I want to do, but use [Google's Protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) as the data transport layer through RPC.

Using the Person message in their addressbook.proto example, I essentially want to do this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myrpc.models import Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['id', 'name', 'email']

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: Google's Protocol buffers as the data transport layer *for what* through RPC? You could use them as the data transport layer for Django ORM models if you wanted. RPC is not a database, it doesn't replace MySQL. If you specifically want to use Google App Engine + Django you don't have to mess with the RPC level stuff at all, you can just use https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine and regular Django models etc

Answer (score -1):

app-engine-patch is no longer maintained and last time I tried it it was so buggy that I was better off reimplementing the middleware that I wanted. I also don't remember them to ever support Django's Admin.

Django's Admin is not compatible with Google App Engine's API for database access. It's actually totally different.

Then there's [Django-norel](https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel/) which attempted to make Django's ORM compatible with GAE and you might have some luck with it, but again it is unmaintained.

So on GAE, don't use a patch because Django 1.2 is already included in the list of available APIs. See this section in their documentation: [Third Party Libraries, Django](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django)

And you won't be able to use Django's Admin. Take your mind off it.